# A GFCI controls all the lights in the bathroom

Tags: gfci

Brand new house, when I test the GFCI in the bathroom, all the lights and fan go off. When I reset the GFCI they all come back on. Is that normal?

Comment: What make and model is the bath fan, and is it mounted over the shower/tub?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 5):

A GFCI receptacle has **line** and **load** connections. This is different from an ordinary receptacle that has two sets of screws that are functionally identical (as long as the magic tabs are not removed).

This may have been deliberately installed this way. But it is quite possible it was a retrofit GFCI (which is a good idea - they are important safety devices for bathrooms) and the installer didn't understand that GFCI line/load is not the same as a regular receptacle's two sets of screws.

The one catch is that if ant of the lights or the fan are above the tub/shower then they must also be GFCI protected. Assuming that is **not** the case:

- Turn off the breaker and make sure power is out (receptacles dead and lights/fan won't turn on)
- Open up the box and pull out the GFCI/breaker. **Take pictures, in case anything goes wrong.**
- Disconnect the wires from the line and load sides.
- Connect all the hot wires (these are wires that were on brass or black screws, should be black wires but not always) together with a wire nut and add a short 12 AWG black wire as a pigtail and connect that to the hot **line** screw.
- Connect all the neutral wires (these are wires that were on silver screws, should be white wires but not always) together with a wire nut and add a short 12 AWG white wire as a pigtail and connect that to the neutral **line** screw.
- Put everything back together and turn on the breaker.
- Verify that the GFCI TEST/RESET buttons work.
- Verify that the receptacles work.
- Verify that lights/fan work and that GFCI TEST does not shut off the lights/fan.

Comment: If  the OP's just moved into the brand new house, it might be better if he contacts the builder for any changes instead of him doing it himself.

Comment: @JACK You're right, I didn't catch that it was a new house. A lot depends on the builder though. Plus, the builder could argue "this is to code" - i.e., valid even though "crazy".

Comment: We don’t know if there is a switch leg where the white is a hot! That code is still allowed in many states if you don’t believe me check the NEC adoption map and notice how many states are 2 code cycles back or don’t even use the code so stating an absolute could cause a short circuit.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not normal. Usually the lights are on a separate circuit that's not GFCI protected and the outlets are on a dedicated, GFCI protected circuit.

Comment: It is legal for the lights to be on the sam circuit and lights are not required to be on a GFCI . But I agree with Jack it is not normal.

Comment: The phantom down voter strikes again without any comments. The OP's problem is allowed but not normal in a brand new house.

Comment: The internet only electricians is my guess I have been getting many on code backed references even on answers a year old.

Comment: @EdBeal  Let me know, I'll upvote ya if I haven't already.

Comment: Not a big deal it’s nice to get recognized, I have been reversing down votes with no explanation for a long time unless really bad

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "normal".

A "GFCI" isn't just a stupid-expensive receptacle.  It's actually a *zone of protection* that can protect other parts of the circuit.

For instance a GFCI circuit breaker protects the entire circuit.

A GFCI recep *obviously* has the 2 sockets in the zone of protection (kinda the whole point, eh? :)  But it can also protect other parts of the circuit, the way a breaker can.

Doing this *is a good thing, generally*.  It means one GFCI is protecting more stuff than just the 2 sockets.  It is efficient use of not-so-cheap assets.

However, protecting lights inside a bathroom is "a bit overkill". Bathroom lights don't generally benefit from GFCI protection (unless they are in the shower, then yes, they do).   Losing the lights when the GFCI trips is annoying and even dangerous if it's a hot curler!  So those are good reasons not to put lights/fan under GFCI protection.  Manassehkatz covers the basics of wiring to select whether a load is inside our outside the GFCI protected zone.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question **is it normal?** As Harper has pointed out "it depends".

*NEC 210.11(C)(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits. Such circuits shall have no other outlets.
Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single bathroom, outlets for other equipment within the same bathroom shall be permitted to be supplied in accordance with 210.23(A)(1) and (A)(2).*

If your Bathroom circuit meets this requirement it is allowed. Otherwise it should only service the bathroom outlets.

If you want to change it because you don't like it then follow manassehkatz's suggestion.

Good luck

Comment: The OP's not asking if it's allowed, only if it's normal. It's not  normal for all the lights to go out when testing a GFCI in a brand new house.

Comment: @JACK - I disagree, it is normal if the contractor wired the bathrooms per 210.11(C)(3). In fact I have seen more bathrooms wired this way than the latter.

Comment: Maybe it's regional because in the four states I've worked in, I've never seen a bathroom go completely dark when testing a GFCI installed in the bathroom.